# How to insert code from sms into textfield correctly?

Tags: swiftui, sms, textfield

I use one time code for inserting code from sms into textfield, it works, but now, after clicking on code on top of the keyboard I can't insert it.
I hope, you can help me

[Thats how does it look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaDGr.jpg)

```
TextField("Введите код", text: $code.value).textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
```

I already use it, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a modifier on View that lets you set the type of content and as a result the system can suggest input to the user:

`func textContentType(_ textContentType: UITextContentType?) -> some View`

You need to pass in `oneTimeCode`

```
TextField("Enter code", text: $code)
    .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
```

Comment: I already use it, but text doesn't insert